# A "paradox" about fourier transform and sampling

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling

Say you want to sample a signal $a(t)$ with a periodical delta function train from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Denote the Fourier transform of $a(t)$ as $A(\omega)$.

Consider two different approaches:

(1) directly sample $a(t)$ itself. The Fourier transform of the sampled result is then given by the sampling of $A(\omega)$ periodically.

(2) sample $a(t)\exp(-i\omega_0 t)$ and subtract the carrier $\exp(-i\omega_0 t)$ after sampling. The Fourier transform of this sampled result is given by periodically sampling $A(\omega+\omega_0)$ .

However, $A(\omega+\omega_0)$ and $A(\omega)$ does not (apparently) have a relation with each other, so there is no guarantee that the result of (1) and (2) are consistent.

What went wrong? I hoped I am not terrible negligent of something very basic.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption that periodically sampling in time domain is completely characterized by periodically sampling in frequency is wrong.

Comment: In which way does this answer your question?

Comment: My initial thought is that since the Fourier transform of a delta train is another delta train, it means that sampling in the time domain (multiply a(t) by a delta train) is Fourier conjugate to sampling in the frequency domain (multiply A(w) by a delta train). However, this is not true: it should be that sampling in the time domain(multiply a(t) by a delta train) is conjugate to convolution in the frequency domain (convolve A(w) by a delta train). So this means that sampling in the time domain is not characterized by sampling in the frequency domain.